# Regex in Yahoo Pipes: append only if match found

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

In Yahoo Pipes, I'm trying to append content to existing string, but only if a match is found in that string.

Specifically, I want to append "#Fracking" to the end of the line, but only if "Hydraulic Fracturing" is found in the item.title.

My regex is as follows (doesn't work): replace `(?(Hydraulic Fracturing)(.*))` with `$1 $#Fracking`

What am I doing wrong? Does Yahoo Pipes not support conditional regex? I could not find an answer to that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do like this:

- pattern: `.*Hydraulic Fracturing.*`
- replacement: `$0#Fracking`

It seems that in Yahoo Pipes the matched string can be back referenced with `$0`.

Here, the `.*` in the front and back make the entire string match if it contains "Hydraulic Fracturing", and then replace the whole thing with itself, plus "#Fracking" appended. If the string doesn't contain "Hydraulic Fracturing" then there will be no replacement.

Comment: Janos, while this works, the string "#Fracking" is appended to the very end of the match string, without a space in between. I tried to insert a space, like this: `$0 #Fracking`, but it did not work. I also tried `$0\s#Fracking`, but it didn't work either. How do I insert a space?

Comment: That's strange. You should be able to insert a simple space there. It works fine for me and I don't see a reason why it wouldn't... Show me your pipe!

Comment: I got it to work, and you're right, a simple space worked. What threw me was the fact that the pipe didn't refresh right away. It worked as expected in a few minutes. Yahoo Pipes must be using caching or throttling or something. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that caching is quite annoying. Look at the debugger in the pipe editor. That is always correct. It can take a couple of minutes for the pipe output to get refreshed.

Comment: New wrinkle: if I wanted to add a hashtag based on two patters, how would I combine them? Example: I want to add "#Oil" only if a) the existing content contains "crude" AND b) does not contain "oil".

Comment: One way could be in 2 steps: 1. append #oil if contains "crude", 2. remove #oil if contains "oil". There might be a clever regex for this, but I'd have to research it. Others might know better. I suggest to ask this in a new question.